# How to find a string in every group and then compare the values of other columns then store it in a new made column

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, data-analysis

I had three data sets which i merged according to some keys and I arranged the 'registrationdatetime' and 'submissiondatetime' according to ascending order. Then I applied groupby to group them by "contestid" and "userhandle". I also had to count number of solvers who entered in a contest before a current solver, i wrote a line for that as well but

Now i have to make a new column called `priorperformanceofsolver` (performance in the recently concluded contest (score of the current solver's submission/s in the most recently concluded contest).

**My aim is to have - every group arranged according to contest_id then there should be 'userhandles' or people who participated in the contest arranged in ascending order of their datetime of arrival in contest so that i count who came in after who in the contest lastly i want to make a new column called priorperformanceofsolver to store the previous performance**

I am sorry it is this long but i really can't figure out if I am right or wrong and i cannot figure out how to make the priorperformanceofsolver column.

I have to search for every contest for every userhandle and find every contest they participated in and which among those contest date was the most recent and what was their score in that recent contest and store in a column called 'priorperformanceofsolver' which has to indicate the score from the most recent contest they participated in. Please help me I am stuck or if there is difficulty in reading this superlong question please comment but help me if possible. I am very new to python

'''

```
    dftotal.groupby(["contestID", "userHandle"])
    dftotal["registerDateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(dftotal.registerDateTime, 
    utc=True)
    dftotal["RegistrationDateTime"] = dftotal["registerDateTime"]
    dftotal["submitDateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(dftotal.submitDateTime, utc 
    =True)
    dftotal["SubmissionDateTime"] = dftotal["submitDateTime"]

    dftotal.sort_values(by=['RegistrationDateTime'])
    dftotal.sort_values(by = ["SubmissionDateTime"])

    dftotal['priorcountofentrants'] = 
    dftotal.groupby(['contestID']).cumcount()
```

'''

```
Data -
contstID userHndle RegistrtnDteTime SubmssnDtTme priorcntofentrnts finalScore

   6638   holo   2012-01-0921:45:20 2012-03-1020:45:20  0            100 
   6638   kolo   2012-01-0922:45:20 2012-03-1023:45:20  1             50   

   8878   holo   2011-01-0921:45:20 2011-01-1020:45:20  0            100 
   8878   kolo   2011-01-0922:45:20 2011-01-1023:45:20  1            100  

expected - 
contstID userHndle RegstrtnDteTme SubmsnDtTm prircntofentrnts finalScore 
                                                                priorperformce

   6638   holo   2012-01-0921:45:20 2012-01-1020:45:20  0       100       100
   6638   kolo   2012-01-0922:45:20 2012-01-1023:45:20  0       50        100
```

so here kolo and holo have their score from the previous contest(recently concluded date wise) displayed beside their name i.e from contest 8878 they scored 100 and 50 so it is displayed next to their name in new contest 6638 then  it happens similarly for the contest 8878 where it has to search for prior performance of the solver

Comment: i'm not sure how you got the scores with the code from above I think we need some more raw data perhaps?

Comment: final score is present in the data itself

Comment: @Datanovice is it fine now? can you understand and suggest how to achieve this?

Comment: @jezrael can you please help me? i know it's quite long but i don't know am i doing it correctly even